# Add signature column in the application

Tags: java, android, digital-signature, stylus-pen

I'm doing a simple courier system using android. How do I do if at the end of the delivery process client have to sign on the phone as the acknowledgement that they received the courier. How do i can do this using android. Any advice, suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing a signature consume lots of space and a in phone device small area is not sufficient to take a signature from client at end of delivery process this is my idea.

Generate a list having delivery details.

--> at delivery time on click of delivered item a view opened.

--> in that view client can perform signature.

--> you can save that signature along with delivery details in DB

--> Delete or transfer items from to Deliver list to Delivered items(Which should be your another view approach)

This is my idea to perfor

m that task. For taking signature you can apply paint method and signature methods ask me if you want help on that too. thanks

```
package com.paintexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawView extends View {

    private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 5f;

    /** Need to track this so the dirty region can accommodate the stroke. **/
    private static final float HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2;

    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();

    /** Optimizes painting by invalidating the smallest possible area. */
    private float lastTouchX;
    private float lastTouchY;
    private final RectF dirtyRect = new RectF();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    }

    /** Erases the signature. */
    public void clear() {
        path.reset();

        // Repaints the entire view.
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            lastTouchX = eventX;
            lastTouchY = eventY;
            // There is no end point yet, so don't waste cycles invalidating.
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // Start tracking the dirty region.
            resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);

            // When the hardware tracks events faster than they are delivered,
            // the
            // event will contain a history of those skipped points.
            int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
            Logger.debug("historySize : " + historySize);
            for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++) {
                float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
                float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
                expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY);
                path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
            }

            // After replaying history, connect the line to the touch point.
            // Logger.debug("eventX " + eventX);
            // Logger.debug("eventY " + eventX);
            //
            // Logger.debug("lastTouchX " + lastTouchX);
            // Logger.debug("lastTouchY " + lastTouchY);
            //
            // if (eventX == lastTouchX && eventY == lastTouchY) {
            //
            // path.addCircle(eventX, eventY, 20, Path.Direction.CW);
            //
            // }

            path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);

            break;

        default:
            Logger.debug("Ignored touch event: " + event.toString());
            return false;
        }

        // Include half the stroke width to avoid clipping.
        invalidate((int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH), (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH), (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH), (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

        lastTouchX = eventX;
        lastTouchY = eventY;

        return true;
    }

    /** Called when replaying history to ensure the dirty region includes all
     * points. */
    private void expandDirtyRect(float historicalX, float historicalY) {
        if (historicalX < dirtyRect.left) {
            dirtyRect.left = historicalX;
        } else if (historicalX > dirtyRect.right) {
            dirtyRect.right = historicalX;
        }
        if (historicalY < dirtyRect.top) {
            dirtyRect.top = historicalY;
        } else if (historicalY > dirtyRect.bottom) {
            dirtyRect.bottom = historicalY;
        }
    }

    /** Resets the dirty region when the motion event occurs. */
    private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY) {

        // The lastTouchX and lastTouchY were set when the ACTION_DOWN
        // motion event occurred.
        dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
        dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
    }
}
```

above is draw class

now add draw view in your activity like this.

```
//Assigning Drawing Board
        drawView = new DrawView(this);
        setContentView(view);
        drawView.requestFocus();
        linearLayout.addView(drawView);
```

you can your different methods of DrawView class for clear/paint and more enjoy

Comment: can you help me in paint method?

Comment: its works fine.... but i have a question... this one show full screen.. how i want to make it like 30% my screen?

Comment: add this draw layout in some region which is 30% of your screen

Comment: sorry didnt get what u mean...:(

Comment: add a view in your activity which is a signature region

then add draw view in that signature region vie